# Boolean column in index and filter sections of explain in postgres

Tags: postgresql, boolean, sql-execution-plan, b-tree-index

I have a table with boolean column - `"is_woman" bool DEFAULT true`

I have an btree index with this column (and some others like age, town and so on) - `is_woman ASC NULLS LAST`

I have a query with this column - `is_woman IS FALSE`

As a result I get an explain:

```
-> Index Scan using woman_idx on superjob (cost=... rows=... width=32) (actual time=... rows=... loops=1)
 Index Cond: (town = 1) AND (is_woman = false) AND (age >= 35) AND (age <= 60))
 Filter: (is_woman IS FALSE)
```

Why there are two is_woman conditions? One in index section, second - in filter?

**UPDATED**

With @dmitry's help I've created two [partial indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-partial.html): one for man with `is_woman is false`, second for woman with `is_woman is true`.

`Explain` for the same query:

```
Bitmap Index Scan on is_woman_woman_idx  (...) (actual time=469.446..469.446 rows=406867 loops=1)
    Index Cond: ((age >= 1) AND (town = 1))
Execution time: 1827.239 ms
```

No `Filter` section and this query works faster:

- actual time `2.227..2754.378` → `469.446..469.446`
- execution time `2792.804 ms` → `1827.239 ms`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

I cannot see anything wrong with this `EXPLAIN` except for the fact the you are indexing `boolean` column (obviously, column has low cardinality field). It **might** be beneficial to use [**Partial Index**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-partial.html) with definition something like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON yourtable WHERE is_woman = FALSE;
```

As for the question itself, you have a query with `WHERE ...` condition. Postgres [**`planner/optimizer`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/planner-optimizer.html) decided to use `woman_idx` index scan instead of sequential one - `Index Cond` is indicated for index scan.

If you can see `Filter` statement it means that the *plan node* checks the condition for each row it scans (in our case each `woman_idx` scan), and outputs only the ones that pass the condition. For details check [**`EXPLAIN`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/using-explain.html) documentation.

Comment: Ok. Maybe boolean has low cardinality but postgres planner decided to use it since this column in Index Cond section. But why there is the same column in Filter section?

Comment: updated last paragraph for clarification - `Filter` statement just indicates that on the top of actual scan of index - additional overhead is spent on particular condition @Anton

Comment: Thank you, I understand 'reasons' of  `Filter` section but this type of check will always return `true`

Comment: As a test I've made column `is_woman_int int2`, made additional index with this column and made two queries 
`Index Scan using woman_idx on superjob  (...) (actual time=2.227..2754.378 rows=406867 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((age >= 1) AND (is_woman = true) AND (town = 1))
   Filter: (is_woman IS TRUE)
 Planning time: 5.566 ms
 Execution time: 2792.804 ms`

 `Index Scan using woman_int_idx on superjob (...) (actual time=0.900..2829.579 rows=406867 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((age >= 1) AND (is_woman_int = 1) AND (town = 1))
 Planning time: 0.406 ms
 Execution time: 2866.855 ms`

Comment: right, filter basically appears whenever you have decent number of records from result, in other words your `WHERE ...` clause is not narrow enough, for `Boolean` column it's almost always a case (low cardinality field) basic scan takes place from `idx` result. You will see `Filter` on integer index `woman_int_idx` when insert ~400k records with, for example `is_woman_int = 100`. `EXPLAIN` will also show `filter` log, because  `is_woman_int = 100` will be returning large number (relative to table records #) of records with the same cardinality @Anton

Comment: Dmitry, thank you again, I understand the `Filter` section basics. Cardinality of `is_woman_int` is the same - I've made it with `update ... set is_woman_int = case when is_woman is false then 0 else 1 end`. By `int` column I want just to test new explain. And I get strange (for me) results. First - `Filter` section with `bool` column does not lead to any degradation. Second - there is no `Filter` section with `int` column with the same values. Thus I still have my question - Why there are two is_woman conditions? One in index section, second - in filter?